# How do you implement a reusable named pipe listener that runs asynchronously?

Tags: .net, asynchronous, named-pipes, reusability

I can't find a good example of how to create a reusable named pipe listener that runs asynchronously. I can make a reusable listener:

```
NamedPipeServerStream pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream("MyPipe", PipeDirection.InOut);

    while (true)
    {
            pipeServer.WaitForConnection();

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(pipeServer);

            MessageBox.Show(reader.ReadLine());

            pipeServer.Disconnect();
    }
```

and I can make an asychronous listener:

```
NamedPipeServerStream pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream("MyPipe", PipeDirection.InOut, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Message, PipeOptions.Asynchronous);

    pipeServer.BeginWaitForConnection((a) =>
    {
        pipeServer.EndWaitForConnection(a);

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(pipeServer);
        MessageBox.Show(reader.ReadLine());

    }, null);
```

But I can't seem to get both going. Is there a good example for this? I'm also concerned about partially sent messages, as I believe that is an issue with asynchronous communications like this.

**Update**:
I'm a little closer.

```
pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream("MyPipe", PipeDirection.InOut, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Message, PipeOptions.Asynchronous);

pipeServer.BeginWaitForConnection((a) =>
{
    pipeServer.EndWaitForConnection(a);

    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(pipeServer);

    while (running)
    {
        String text = reader.ReadLine();

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(text) == false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(text);
        }
    }

    MessageBox.Show("Done!");

}, null);
```

That will read successfully once, and will continue looping, with ReadLine returning an empty empty string after the initial successful read. So it's clearly not blocking, and is attempting to read again. The problem is if I send the same message a second time, it doesn't get picked up, and my pipe writer says it's receiving error 2316 (though I can't figure out what that means). I think I just need to do something similar to this where the pipe gets cleaned up each time, like the first code sample I listed, but I haven't gotten that to work yet.

Comment: System (i.e. Win32 API) error codes are here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681381(VS.85).aspx  But there is no error 2316... are you sure that was the error code? Could you include full details of the exception (including type and message?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see this until just now, and I'm no longer producing the error. This is the code that produced it, on the writer's end: if (pipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
  {
   cout << "Error: " << GetLastError();
  }

Comment: It turns out it was error 231. The 6 was output from something else.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think I've got it:

```
pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream("MyPipe", PipeDirection.InOut, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Message, PipeOptions.Asynchronous);

Boolean connectedOrWaiting = false;

Byte[] buffer = new Byte[65535];

while (running)
{
    if (!connectedOrWaiting)
    {                   
        pipeServer.BeginWaitForConnection((a) => { pipeServer.EndWaitForConnection(a); }, null);

        connectedOrWaiting = true;
    }

    if (pipeServer.IsConnected)
    {
        Int32 count = pipeServer.Read(buffer, 0, 65535);

        if (count > 0)
        {
            UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
            String message = encoding.GetString(buffer, 0, count);

            MessageBox.Show(message);
        }

        pipeServer.Disconnect();

        connectedOrWaiting = false;
    }
}
```

This will accept multiple message as they come, and will shut down as soon as running is set to false (in another thread, obviously). It appears to be what I need. Can someone verify that I'm not doing anything silly?

Answer (score 2):

> I'm also concerned about partially sent messages

They are not an issue with NamedPipes using the native (Win32) APIs, so I very much doubt they are a problem using .NET. However in the [native documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365150%28VS.85%29.aspx) it does say:

> Data is written to the pipe as a stream of messages. The pipe treats the bytes written during each write operation as a message unit. The GetLastError function returns ERROR_MORE_DATA when a message is not read completely. This mode can be used with either PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE or PIPE_READMODE_BYTE.

(Note `ERROR_MORE_DATA` is 234.)

The documentation also says, for flag `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` (the native equivalent of `PipeOptions.Asynchronous`):

> Overlapped mode is enabled. If this mode is enabled, functions performing read, write, and connect operations that may take a significant time to be completed can return immediately.

I've always used asynchronous IO operations with asynchronous named pipes (i.e. [`Stream.BeginRead`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.beginread.aspx)), but this does mean losing the functionality of a [`TextReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textreader.aspx), but then `PipeTransmissionMode.Message` is defined in terms of transmitting groups of bytes anyway.

Comment: Well that's good to know. I'm very open to BeginRead, but I don't think I'm using it right. I establish my connection, but the number of bytes read (the return from EndRead) is always 0. Do you know of a good example? Preferably one that is reusable?